# Dealing with character variables containing semicolons in CSV files

Tags: r, readr

I have a file separated by semicolons in which one of the variables of type character contains semicolon inside it. The readr::read_csv2 function splits the contents of those variables that have semicolons into more columns, messing up the formatting of the file.

For example, when using read_csv2 to open the file below, Bill's age column will show jogging, not 41.

File:

```
name;hobbies;age
Jon;cooking;38
Bill;karate;jogging;41
Maria;fishing;32
```

Considering that the original file doesn't contain quotes around the character type variables, how can I import the file so that karate and jogging belong in the hobbies column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### read.csv()

You can use the `read.csv()` function. But there would be some warning messages (or use `suppressWarnings()` to wrap around the `read.csv()` function). If you wish to avoid warning messages, using the `scan()` method in the next section.

```
library(dplyr)

read.csv("./path/to/your/file.csv", sep = ";", 
         col.names = c("name", "hobbies", "age", "X4")) %>% 
  mutate(hobbies = ifelse(is.na(X4), hobbies, paste0(hobbies, ";" ,age)), 
         age = ifelse(is.na(X4), age, X4)) %>% 
  select(-X4)
```

### scan() file

You can first `scan()` the CSV file as a character vector first, then split the string with pattern `;` and change it into a dataframe. After that, do some `mutate()` to identify your target column and remove unnecessary columns. Finally, use the first row as the column name.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

semicolon_file <- scan(file = "./path/to/your/file.csv", character())

semicolon_df <- data.frame(str_split(semicolon_file, ";", simplify = T))

semicolon_df %>% 
  mutate(X4 = na_if(X4, ""), 
         X2 = ifelse(is.na(X4), X2, paste0(X2, ";" ,X3)), 
         X3 = ifelse(is.na(X4), X3, X4)) %>% 
  select(-X4) %>% 
  janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

### Output

```
   name        hobbies age
2   Jon        cooking  38
3  Bill karate;jogging  41
4 Maria        fishing  32
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the columns `name` and `age` with a single entry per observation and `hobbies` with possible multiple entries the following approach works:

1. read in the file line by line instead of treating  it as a table:

```
tmp <- readLines(con <- file("table.csv"))
close(con)
```

2. Find the position of the separator in every row. The entry before the first separator is the name the entry after the last is the age:

```
separator_pos <- gregexpr(";", tmp)
name <- character(length(tmp) - 1)
age <- integer(length(tmp) - 1)
hobbies <- vector(length=length(tmp) - 1, "list")
```

3. fill the three elements using a for loop:

```
# the first line are the colnames
for(line in 2:length(tmp)){
     # from the beginning of the row to the first";"
     name[line-1] <- strtrim(tmp[line], separator_pos[[line]][1] -1) 
     # between the first ";" and the last ";".
     # Every ";" is a different elemet of the list
     hobbies[line-1] <- strsplit(substr(tmp[line], separator_pos[[line]][1] +1,  
                                        separator_pos[[line]][length(separator_pos[[line]])]-1),";")
     #after the last ";", must be an integer
     age[line-1] <- as.integer(substr(tmp[line],separator_pos[[line]][length(separator_pos[[line]])]+1, 
                               nchar(tmp[line])))
}
```

4. Create a separate matrix to hold the hobbies and fill it rowwise:

```
hobbies_matrix <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow = length(hobbies), ncol = max(lengths(hobbies)))
for(line in 1:length(hobbies)) 
    hobbies_matrix[line,1:length(hobbies[[line]])] <-  hobbies[[line]]
```

5. Add all variable to a data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name = name, hobbies = hobbies_matrix, age = age)
> df
   name hobbies.1 hobbies.2 age
1   Jon   cooking      <NA>  38
2  Bill    karate   jogging  41
3 Maria   fishing      <NA>  32
```

Comment: why do you have `con` and you are not using it? just ` readLines("table.csv")` should read the lines

Comment: @Onyambu I thought the con argument of readLines must be a file connection. I didn't know it can be a string. Is it possible that the oprion of using a string was added some time in the past five years?

Comment: Cant tell. As long as I have used the function, I have been able to use a string. Been working with R for less than 10yrs though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
read.csv(text=gsub('(^[^;]+);|;([^;]+$)', '\\1,\\2', readLines('file.csv')))

   name        hobbies age
1   Jon        cooking  38
2  Bill karate;jogging  41
3 Maria        fishing  32
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd ask whoever generated the file to do it properly next time :) but of course this is not always possible.

Easiest way is probably to read the lines from the file into a character vector, then clean up and make a data frame by string matching.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# skip header, add it later
dataset <- read_lines("your_file.csv", skip = 1)

dataset_df <- data.frame(name = str_match(dataset, "^(.*?);")[, 2], 
                         hobbies = str_match(dataset, ";(.*?);\\d")[, 2], 
                         age = as.numeric(str_match(dataset, ";(\\d+)$")[, 2]))
```

Result:

```
   name        hobbies age
1   Jon        cooking  38
2  Bill karate;jogging  41
3 Maria        fishing  32
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the file created in the Note at the end

**1)** `read.pattern` can read this by specifying the pattern as a regular expression with the portions within parentheses representing the fields.

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern("hobbies.csv", pattern = '^(.*?);(.*);(.*)$', header = TRUE)
##    name        hobbies age
## 1   Jon        cooking  38
## 2  Bill karate;jogging  41
## 3 Maria        fishing  32
```

**2) Base R** Using base R we can read in the lines, put quotes around the middle field and then read it in normally.

```
L <- "hobbies.csv" |>
  readLines() |>
  sub(pattern = ';(.*);', replacement = ';"\\1";')
read.csv2(text = L)
##    name        hobbies age
## 1   Jon        cooking  38
## 2  Bill karate;jogging  41
## 3 Maria        fishing  32
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "name;hobbies;age
Jon;cooking;38
Bill;karate;jogging;41
Maria;fishing;32
"
cat(Lines, file = "hobbies.csv")
```